# loop inside stored procedure always prints last value forever

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have access to a database while I am learning pl/SQL. It can feel overwhelming at first when it comes to Oracle and banshee.

All I want to do is a loop through the contents of what a cursor selects from the applicants' table and to print out the first name of the applicants.

I am not too familiar with the syntax yet so maybe something is wrong but the loop prints through fine until it gets to the last value and then it just prints it forever until its unable to allocate more memory.

Thank you in advance and sorry if this is a silly question.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE APPLICANTS IS
first_name APPLICANT.FNAME%TYPE;
CURSOR fnameCursor IS
SELECT FNAME
FROM APPLICANT
ORDER BY FNAME DESC;
BEGIN
OPEN fnameCursor;
LOOP
FETCH fnameCursor INTO first_name;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(first_name);
END LOOP;
CLOSE fnameCursor;

END APPLICANTS;
/

EXECUTE APPLICANTS;
```

Comment: The Oracle documentation is comprehensive, online and free. [ For instance here is the section on PL/SQL loops](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/controlstatements.htm#GUID-4CD12F11-2DB8-4B0D-9E04-DF983DCF9358). You should bookmark it, because it will answer many if not all of [basic syntax questions like example 4-25 does for this one](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/controlstatements.htm#GUID-A2EBEED5-117D-41A2-99BC-7031EBB5D6D1__CIHGGFCG).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an `EXIT` condition in your loop.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE applicants IS
         first_name   applicant.fname%TYPE;
         CURSOR fnamecursor IS SELECT fname
                               FROM applicant
         ORDER BY fname DESC;
    BEGIN
         OPEN fnamecursor;
         LOOP
              FETCH fnamecursor INTO first_name;
              EXIT WHEN fnamecursor%NOTFOUND; -- This line is required.
              dbms_output.put_line(first_name);
         END LOOP;
         CLOSE fnamecursor;
    END applicants;
    /
```